# Table not updating when chaging the service.xml and building the service in liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am developing the custom portlet for liferay.
My problem is once I create service builder and build the service then in my database the table is created. I have some changes in my service.xml (some table column is added) but now when I build the service my database table is not updating the table column. It is as same as before.

So can anyone guide me that why this happens? I am new to liferay and there is always some changes will occurs so I need to solve  this problem.

Comment: It is a bit silly of me to ask, but still, I hope you know that the tables are altered or created only when the portlet is deployed and not when we just build the service. Thanks

Comment: ya.i have deployed that server.but it wasn't working.just restart my system make it works...hope will not get that error again

Comment: Actually this is intermittent during development. I wonder why. Anyways so this question is done then.

Comment: yup..and thanks for your answer..u always ther to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got soution of this problem..

1)..try to delete your portlet from liferay...
2)..then again redeploy that portlet..that solved my problem

if anyone have same problem then can try this way